# Allow remote server to access API server on localhost

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I'm trying to do some home automation with my Raspberry Pi.
Right now I've set up a Node+Express API server (address `http://192.168.100.100:3000`, local folder `~/api`), used to send the signal to a Air Conditioner and get the info from it.

Aside I've built a webapp with Vuejs to manage the AC, and setup a Nginx server to access the webapp (address: `http://192.168.100.100`, local folder `~/controller/dist`).
Everything works perfectly on the local network, but I want to access to everything remotely. So I've forwarded the port `80`, and I can access the webapp over the internet, but it doesn't work, because it can't access the API server.

Is it normal, and I have to forward also the port `3000`, or is there a way to tell the app to look for the API on the localhost?

Comment: You might want to checkout https://ngrok.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both should work in the local network because everybody knows who's who. If the communication is server to server, both should work too because it's the same scenario. But if client perform Ajax to communicate to server, you should forward port 3000 too. Because the request is out of the local context (if you are out of your network).

server to server:  localhost ->  localhost

client(browser) to server:  internet -> localhost

You could avoid the forward if server(local) perform a request to a client(remote).

Comment: Thanks, now it's clear: using ajax it's like the webapp is "just" a collector of links to the API server, and when you call an endpoint the call starts from your client, not the remote server. Otherwise, e.g., when using PHP + MySql the call from the PHP server to the MySql one happens server to server, so the address of the sql is "localhost". (I'm just pointing this out to check if I got it right :)

Comment: @Camillo Yes, it's exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can forward port 3000, and it should work.

Another option is to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com). It allows you to open a tunnel (regardless of your firewall settings) straight to your API. All you have to do it register a *free* account and you will be able to have a single tunnel running indefinitely. Only drawback is that you need to use their shortUrl (Like `https://asdasd12.ngrok.io` which changes every time you restart. You can pay to get rid of that, and get a permanent subdomain(Like `https://myniceapi.ngrok.io`)